# Passing a function as argument which uses the argument of parent function but also has it's own argument

Tags: javascript, function, callback, functional-programming, arguments

I just started playing around with functional programming and am trying to pass a function as an argument of another function. However the function that I am trying to pass also has arguments like so:

```
function splitStringBy(string, type, func) {

    // Split string by type.
    var splitArray = string.split(type);
    console.log(splitArray);

    // Do something with the array.
    func !== undefined ? func(splitArray) : null;
}



function loopArray(array, func) {

    // Loop through array.
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        func(array[i]);
    }
}
```

I need to pass splitArray to my loopArray()

Here's how I'm trying to call it:

```
splitStringBy($scope.textSpace, "<br>", loopArray(splitArray, function() {
            console.log('It worked!');
}));
```

Console comes up with Error: splitArray is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than passing `loopArray` as a function, you're actually calling it, then passing its return value to `splitStringBy`. Since `splitArray` isn't defined when you first reference it, it's throwing that error.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
function splitStringBy(string, type, func) {

    // Split string by type.
    var splitArray = string.split(type);
    console.log(splitArray);

    // Do something with the array.
    func !== undefined ? func(splitArray) : null;
}

function loopArray(func) {
    // Return function for looping.
    return function(array) {
        // Loop through array.
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            func(array[i]);
        }
    }
}

splitStringBy($scope.textSpace, "<br>", loopArray(function() {
        console.log('It worked!');
}));
```

This is called currying, where a function passes a function as a return value. `loopArray` will create a function, then return it. We then pass the newly made function to `splitStringBy`, which then invokes it.

Comment: So I'm guessing if you wanted to do the same thing with the function within loopArray you'd do the same, right?

Comment: Yes, but I don't really know why you would ever need double-currying in a situation like this.